# Docker container is not removable

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, ubuntu-21.04

What I have tried:

[image]

`sudo service docker restart`  doesn't change the result

Exact containers behind are:
[image]

Suprised that `sudo` is still not enough

Working solution is to reboot system to kill dockers... But this is not a solution. Thanks in advance if anybody knows what to do with this

Comment: is your localhost or some cloud? Try manually the docker ps (get container name) and docker rm -f <container_name>   and share us the result

Comment: Take a looke here: https://forums.docker.com/t/can-not-stop-docker-container-permission-denied-error/41142/5